# Auto increment char varying column prefixed with some characters

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.2, auto-increment

I have a table in PostgreSQL for hospital patients and I want to make a primary key for it as `PAT0000001` (`char varying`) and to keep that field as **auto-increment** as well.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If **every** key value has the prefix `PAT` there is no sense in storing it. Create a `serial` column and a view that formats the number as desired. Additionally: the value of a primary key has **no** meaning whatsoever. You should not care about the values in that column, the only thing you need to care about is that they are unique.

Comment: Thanx buddy, But can't we just make any varchar as auto-increament..?

Comment: "*can't we just make any varchar as auto-increament*" - that is not the correct question. What you are trying to achieve simply doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have "auto-increment" fields in the sense of MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but I'm guessing you mean `SERIAL`.

If so, yes, what you describe is possible, but please, please don't do this.

A `SERIAL` is just shorthand for a `CREATE SEQUENCE` and a default value. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE blah(
   id serial primary key
);
```

is actually shorthand for:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE blah_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE blah (
    id integer primary key default nextval('blah_id_seq'::regclass)
);

ALTER SEQUENCE blah_id_seq OWNED BY blah.id;
```

You can use this knowledge to cast the `nextval` return to a character type, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE thisiswrong (
    id text primary key default CAST(nextval('thisiswrong_id_seq'::regclass) AS text)
);
```

but again, I beg of you, **do not do this**. It's horrible. It's wrong. You will regret it. *Whatever you are trying to do, there is a better way to do it than this*.

I have intentionally *not* shown how to generate a formatted field like `PAT000001`, but you can use *any expression* in a `DEFAULT`, not just a `CAST`. So look at the `to_char` function or the `format` function for how to do this if you insist.

The *correct* way to do what you want to do is *not to do it*. Get the *application* to display codes like `PAT000001` when it sees a primary key value for `patient_id` like `1`. The user never needs to know that you're just storing integers.

If you want other prefixes like `PAT`, `DOC`, etc, use a *composite primary key*, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE saner_ish (
    categorycode varchar(3) CHECK (length(categorycode) = 3),
    patient_id integer default nextval('saner_ish_patient_id'::regclass),
    PRIMARY KEY (categorycode, patient_id)
);
```

(possibly with an `enum` type, an `IN` list, or whatever for validation).

Then in the application turn `PAT00001` into `('PAT', 1)` for queries, and reverse it for display to the user.

Comment: Thanx for you generous response....!
I really appreciate it...!
_@

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing requirements for ***representation*** and ***storage***. That's a common misconception for people coming from spreadsheet programs, where you typically do both at once.

Just store a [**`serial`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column. The underlying `integer` column occupies 4 bytes and is very efficient for various purposes in the DB. In comparison, 'PAT0000001' as [`text` or `varchar`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) occupies 11 bytes, is subject to collation and not quite as efficient overall.

You don't seem to need a multicolumn primary key. That would be *needless complication*. Go with a simple **single-column surrogate primary key**, even if you should have various "types" of patients.

```
CREATE TABLE patient (
   patient_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , col1 text NOT NULL
 , col2 date NOT NULL
   ... -- more columns
);
```

For *presentation* needs, create a [**view**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html):

```
CREATE VIEW patient_pretty AS
SELECT to_char(1, '"PAT"FM0000000') AS patient_code, col1, col2
FROM   patient;
```

I suggest to use a different column name consistently for the formatted ID to avoid confusion. `patient_code` in my example.

The [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) expression is the only slightly tricky thing here. Note the `FM` modifier to avoid a leading blank (placeholder for a possible negative sign).

Now, when you want pretty display, use the view `patient_pretty` as dop-in replacement for table `patient` -  or just the expression.